# How Does Kafka Offsets And Flink Checkpoints Work Together?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

The relationship between Kafka offsets and Flink checkpoints confusing me. So **Kafka** stores the offset of the last message you've read. On top of that **Flink** has the checkpoint system. But why do we need to checkpoint the offsets in Flink when Kafka already stores it the last offset?

**Consider this example:** The currenct Kafka offset for the consumer group is at 2005. The last Flink checkpoint has taken at offset 2000. What's is going to happen when I restart the Flink app from the checkpoint? Is it going to start reading from 2000 and resend messages between 2001 to 2005? That doesn't make sense to me because without Flink storing the offset, it would already restart from 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Flink will replay records starting with the offset saved in the checkpoint. This is a fundamental aspect to how Flink provides support for exactly-once processing...data can be processed multiple times (replayed), BUT it will only effect the state in operates once, because all operator state will also be restored to match the result of processing records up to the saved offset.

Sinks are a bit different, in that they need to support transactions to provide exactly once guarantees. Basically data sent to a sink "between" checkpoints is part of a transaction, and only when the next checkpoint is successfully committed will the transaction also be committed.

Comment: Are kafka offset commits disabled by Flink sources then?

Comment: They aren't disabled, but they aren't used (unless you explicitly configure the Kafka source to use them).